# I want to match similar words between columns

Tags: r, matching

| 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| loud | complaint | problems |
| pain | stress | confused |
| dull | pain | stress |

this is my data set and I would like to reorganize the rows so that if there is a word that appears in each column it is transferred to a corresponding row.  For example

| 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| loud | NA | NA |
| pain | pain | NA |
| dull | NA | NA |
| NA | complaint | NA |
| NA | stress | stress |
| NA | NA | confused |
| NA | NA | problems |

etc., so that every word gets its own row and if the word in that row appears in the column it is matched up with the other columns

I have been looking how to do this but cannot find good code.  One idea i was given was create a list of all appearing words and then try to match them to each column but still havent found code for this.

Answer (score 8):

We may use `match` in `base R` - get the `unique` elements from the `unlist`ed data as a `vector`, loop over the columns, get the index of the matching elements, and `replace` the index with the matched elements and convert to a data.frame after taking care of the lengths

```
v1 <- unique(unlist(df1))
lst1 <- lapply(df1, \(x) 
   {i1 <- match(x, v1)
   replace(rep(NA, max(i1)), i1, v1[i1])
 })
list2DF(lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
 1.0       2.0      3.0
1 loud      <NA>     <NA>
2 pain      pain     <NA>
3 dull      <NA>     <NA>
4 <NA> complaint     <NA>
5 <NA>    stress   stress
6 <NA>      <NA> problems
7 <NA>      <NA> confused
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`1.0` = c("loud", "pain", "dull"), `2.0` = c("complaint", 
"stress", "pain"), `3.0` = c("problems", "confused", "stress"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: The second lapply in `list2DF` isn't necessary; you can just use the `nrow` argument: `list2DF(lst1, nrow = max(lengths(lst1))`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `tidyverse` version.

```r
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
x = tibble(`1.0` = c("loud", "pain", "dull"),
           `2.0` = c("complaint", "stress", "pain"),
           `3.0` = c("problems", "confused", "stress"))

x %>% 
  gather("version", "value") %>% 
  mutate(id = value) %>% 
  spread(version, value) %>% 
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   `1.0` `2.0`     `3.0`   
#>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>   
#> 1 <NA>  complaint <NA>    
#> 2 <NA>  <NA>      confused
#> 3 dull  <NA>      <NA>    
#> 4 loud  <NA>      <NA>    
#> 5 pain  pain      <NA>    
#> 6 <NA>  <NA>      problems
#> 7 <NA>  stress    stress
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If you need to arrange the rows in the order of occurrence you can change the second statement to

```
mutate(id = fct_inorder(value)) %>%
```

NOTE: The functions `gather` and `spread` are superseded by `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` functions. In my opinion, the older are a bit easier to use and are good enough for this case. The new functions are much more powerful.

Answer (score 4):

Fast + efficient data.table solution:

```
x <- data.table(`1.0` = c("loud", "pain", "dull"),
           `2.0` = c("complaint", "stress", "pain"),
           `3.0` = c("problems", "confused", "stress"))

dcast(unique(melt(x, measure.vars = names(x))), value ~ variable)

       value  1.0       2.0      3.0
1: complaint <NA> complaint     <NA>
2:  confused <NA>      <NA> confused
3:      dull dull      <NA>     <NA>
4:      loud loud      <NA>     <NA>
5:      pain pain      pain     <NA>
6:  problems <NA>      <NA> problems
7:    stress <NA>    stress   stress
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `stack` + `reshape`

```
reshape(
  transform(stack(df), v = values),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "values",
  timevar = "ind"
)[-1]
```

which gives

```
  v.x1      v.x2     v.x3
1 loud      <NA>     <NA>
2 pain      pain     <NA>
3 dull      <NA>     <NA>
4 <NA> complaint     <NA>
5 <NA>    stress   stress
7 <NA>      <NA> problems
8 <NA>      <NA> confused
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(x1 = c("loud", "pain", "dull"), x2 = c("complaint", 
"stress", "pain"), x3 = c("problems", "confused", "stress")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```