# Join two data frames with different dimensions and match

Tags: r, join, merge, string-matching

This is a two-part question. I would like to join/ merge two data frames into one. They each have only one column but different numbers of rows. Some observations match; others do not.

```
df1 <- c("John", "Tommy", "Linda", "Cole")
df2 <- c("Tom", "John", "Bruce")
as.data.frame(df1)
as.data.frame(df2)
```

After joining them together, I need to put matching observations on the same row. I.e., John(df1) will be on the same row as John(df2), and same with Tommy(df1) and Tom(df2). This may involve fuzzy match as variations of names (Tom/ Tommy) will need to be matched.

If there is an observation in df1 that does not exist in df2 (like Linda), I would like a NA in that row for df2. Vice-versa for Bruce.

Desired output:

| df1 | df2 |
| --- | --- |
| John | John |
| Tommy | Tom |
| Linda | NA |
| Cole | NA |
| NA | Bruce |

Please advise. I have tried variations of functions merge, match, join etc but without success. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [similar to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75986984/i-want-to-match-similar-words-between-columns/75987214#75987214)

Comment: Please show the code that is not working.  Also I would say that you want to separate out the basic how to merge (that's pretty easy) from the fuzzy matching.   Start with getting the exact match to work.

Comment: Thanks @Elin, I agree with you about one thing at a time (from simple to more complex).

Comment: I was updating the question with code that did not work but @Maël beat me to it with the answer. Thank you @Maël!

Comment: And thank you @peter861222 for linking that similar post; it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fuzzyjoin`:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(df1 = c("John", "Tommy", "Linda", "Cole"))
df2 <- data.frame(df2 = c("Tom", "John", "Bruce"))

fuzzyjoin::stringdist_full_join(df1, df2, by = c(df1 = "df2"))

#     df1   df2
# 1  John  John
# 2 Tommy   Tom
# 3 Linda  <NA>
# 4  Cole  <NA>
# 5  <NA> Bruce
```